# Fortigate Identity Policy and Custom Services

Tags: fortinet, fortigate

Is it me or is it impossible to have the user\pass portal for services there are NOT pre-defined in Fortigate?

I've been trying for a few hours to force anyone who tries to access a certain server on port 8080 to get that portal but for some reason it just doesnt work. On the other hand, when trying a pre-defined service like plain http it works almost immediately.

What could I possibly be missing?

Comment: Have you double checked that you have enabled and setup Identity Based Policy against the right firewall policy ?

Comment: What do you mean?
I created the policy from scratch.
With or without other policies that allow the traffic it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a slight misunderstanding of how Identity Policy works.

You MUST goto a HTTP\HTTPS page in order to get the portal. And I mean either port 80 or 443. You CAN NOT get the portal on any other port. 
However, once successfully authenticating everything else becomes available. Even my 8080 port.